# Save values in db with submit button only

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to save some values into db, on first page i am running some matches and on the the 2nd page i need to save values. on first page only click button is shown to user, when he clicks , the values are stored.

code

```
<form action="ms_insert.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Claim your daily bonus" name="test">
</form>
```

How can i submit all the values that are outside the form and send them to the   ms_insert.php and process the values.

What i need to achieve it like this.

some values shall be matched , on successful match it will save the enteries into the db.

Here is the exact code that i am using now :

```
<?php
if ( $thismemberinfo[msurf] >= $msurfclicks ) {
$sql=$Db1->query("INSERT INTO d_bonus VALUES('$userid','0.02',NOW())"); 
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "wrong";
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="match">
<input type="submit" value="Claim your daily bonus $o.o2" name="claim">
</form>
```

I want this php code to excute when user click the submit button.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" .../>`, sessions...?

Comment: Why do you need to submit form elements that reside outside the `form` tag? It's there to contain them.

Comment: these are not the form elements. I have some conditions that are already outside form, once user clicks the submit button, I need them to store the values in the db,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Php page with html form inside execute php code before form is completed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21834925/php-page-with-html-form-inside-execute-php-code-before-form-is-completed)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I can think of doing this:

- Simply set the post variable to another value as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418136/3199478):

  ```
  $_POST['text'] = 'another value';
  ```

  This will override the previous value corresponding to text key of the array. The $_POST is super global associative array and you can change the values like a normal php array.
- Second would be to use _SESSION tags as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16778482/3199478) post:

  In the first.php:

  ```
  $_SESSION['favcolor'] = 'green';
  ```

  In ms_insert.php:

  ```
  echo $_SESSION['favcolor']; // green
  ```

P.S. You can also use [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php)

Additional sources:

- http://www.felixgers.de/teaching/php/hidden1.html

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21835020/3199478) post this might help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Javascript with a XHR object for example or try to insert your values to store in hidden inputs.

**Solution 1 : AJAX, for example :**

*Your JS (Here with Jquery):*

```
function saveInDb(){

    /* Retrieve your values in your page : */
    var myValue1 = $('#value1Id').val();
    var myValue2 = $('#value2Id').val();

    /*Create a Jquery ajax object : */
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ms_insert.php",
      data: { "value1": myValue1, "value2": myValue2 }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved");
    });
}
```

*Your HTML :*

```
<span id="value1Id">My value 1</span>
<span id="value2Id">My value 2</span>
<button onclick=saveInDb()></button>
```

**Solution 2 : the HTML  with hidden inputs :**

```
<form action="ms_insert.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" value="My value 1" name="value1">
   <input type="hidden" value="My value 2" name="value2">
   <input type="submit" value="Claim your daily bonus" name="test">
</form>
```

Comment: Please show how. The answer as is should be a comment.